# Pandas groupby with identification of an element with max value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a dataframe with sales results of items with different pricing rules:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_3 = pd.DataFrame()

# Create datetimes and data
df_1['item'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
df_1['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='D')
df_1['price_rule'] = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']
df_1['sales']= [2, 4, 1, 5, 7]
df_1['clicks']= [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

df_2['item'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
df_2['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='D')
df_2['price_rule'] = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a']
df_2['sales']= [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
df_2['clicks']= [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

df_3['item'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
df_3['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='D')
df_3['price_rule'] = ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
df_3['sales']= [6, 5, 4, 5, 6]
df_3['clicks']= [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3])
df = df.sort_values(['item', 'date'])
df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

It results with:

```
    item    date    price_rule  sales   clicks
0   1   2018-01-01       a       2       7
0   1   2018-01-01       b       2       7
0   1   2018-01-01       b       6       7
1   1   2018-01-02       b       4       8
1   1   2018-01-02       b       3       8
1   1   2018-01-02       a       5       8
2   2   2018-01-03       a       1       9
2   2   2018-01-03       a       4       9
2   2   2018-01-03       b       4       9
3   2   2018-01-04       b       5       10
3   2   2018-01-04       a       5       10
3   2   2018-01-04       a       5       10
4   2   2018-01-05       b       7       11
4   2   2018-01-05       a       6       11
4   2   2018-01-05       b       6       11
```

My goal is to:
1. group all items by day (to get a single row for each item and given day)
2. aggregate 'clicks' with "sum"
3. **generate a "winning_pricing_rule"** columns as following:
 - for a given item and given date, take a pricing rule with the highest 'sales' value
 - in case of 'draw' (see eg: item 2 on 2018-01-03  in a sample above): choose just one of them (that's rare in my dataset, so it can be random...)

I imagine the result to look like this:

```
  item  date       winning_price_rule   clicks
0   1   2018-01-01      b               21
1   1   2018-01-02      a               24
2   2   2018-01-03      b               27  <<remark: could also be a (due to draw)
3   2   2018-01-04      a               30  <<remark: could also be b (due to draw)
4   2   2018-01-05      b               33
```

I tried:

```
a.groupby(['item', 'date'], as_index = False).agg({'sales':'sum','revenue':'max'})
```

but failed to identify a winning pricing rule.

Any ideas? Many Thanks for help :)

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `price_rule` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so for `winning_price_rule` is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) - get index value by maximum `sales` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html), because also is necessary aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('price_rule')
         .groupby(['item', 'date'])
         .agg({'sales':'idxmax', 'clicks':'sum'})
         .reset_index())
```

For pandas 0.25.+ is possible use:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('price_rule')
         .groupby(['item', 'date'])
         .agg(winning_pricing_rule=pd.NamedAgg(column='sales', aggfunc='idxmax'),clicks=pd.NamedAgg(column='clicks', aggfunc="sum'))
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: OK. But what about clicks? In Your example 'clicks' column sums up 'sales'. In my case I need here a sum of all clicks from original df (eg. 21 for item 1 on 2018-01-01. ???

Comment: @Andrzej Wodecki Sorry, you are right, answer was edited.