# Pandas rolling sum with groupby and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with a timeseries of sales of different items with customer analytics. For each item and a given day I want to compute:

- a share of my best customer in last 2 days total sales
- a share of my top customers (from a list) in last 2 days total sales

I've tried solutions provided here:

- for rolling sum:
  [Pandas sum over a date range for each category separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521181/pandas-sum-over-a-date-range-for-each-category-separately/58521513?noredirect=1#comment103375185_58521513)
- for conditioned groupby: [Pandas groupby with identification of an element with max value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539567/pandas-groupby-with-identification-of-an-element-with-max-value-in-another-colum/58539704?noredirect=1#comment103416452_58539704)

An example dataframe is can be generated by:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_3 = pd.DataFrame()

# Create datetimes and data
df_1['item'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df_1['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=7, freq='D')
df_1['customer'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
df_1['sales'] = [2, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 3]

df_2['item'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df_2['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=7, freq='D')
df_2['customer'] = ['b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a']
df_2['sales'] = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]

df_3['item'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df_3['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=7, freq='D')
df_3['customer'] = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b']
df_3['sales'] = [6, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3])
df = df.sort_values(['item', 'date'])
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

and looks like this:

| item | date | customer | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | a | 2 |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | b | 2 |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | b | 6 |
| 1 | 2018-01-02 | b | 4 |
| 1 | 2018-01-02 | b | 3 |
| 1 | 2018-01-02 | c | 5 |
| 1 | 2018-01-03 | c | 1 |
| 1 | 2018-01-03 | c | 4 |
| 1 | 2018-01-03 | a | 2 |
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | a | 5 |
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | a | 2 |
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | c | 3 |
| 2 | 2018-01-05 | b | 7 |
| 2 | 2018-01-05 | a | 3 |
| 2 | 2018-01-05 | b | 4 |
| 2 | 2018-01-06 | b | 2 |
| 2 | 2018-01-06 | c | 5 |
| 2 | 2018-01-06 | a | 5 |
| 2 | 2018-01-07 | c | 3 |
| 2 | 2018-01-07 | a | 6 |
| 2 | 2018-01-07 | b | 6 |

I expect the following results:

| item | date | sales_at_day | sales_last_2_days | a_share | top_share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 10 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2018-01-02 | 12 | 10 | 0.20 | 0.20 |
| 1 | 2018-01-03 | 7 | 22 | 0.09 | 0.09 |
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | 10 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2018-01-05 | 14 | 10 | 0.70 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 2018-01-06 | 12 | 24 | 0.29 | 0.42 |
| 2 | 2018-01-07 | 15 | 26 | 0.31 | 0.50 |

where,

`a_share` is the share of sales of customer 'a' in total sales in last 2 days (not including present day)
`top_share` is the share of sales of customers in a

```
top_cust = ['a', 'c']
```

list in total sales in last 2 days (not including present day)

Any ideas? Many Thanks in advance :)

Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
#custom rolling with shift first day
f = lambda x: x.rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum().shift()

#aggregate sum
df1 = df.groupby(['item','date'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
#apply custom rolling per groups
df1['sales_last_2_days'] = df1.groupby('item')['sales'].apply(f).reset_index(drop=True, level=0)

#filter customer a and aggregate sum
a = df[df['customer'].eq('a')].groupby(['item','date'])['sales'].sum().rename('a_share')
#add new column to original
df1 = df1.join(a, on=['item','date'])
#applt custom rolling per groups and divide
df1['a_share'] = df1.groupby('item')['a_share'].apply(f).reset_index(drop=True, level=0) / df1['sales_last_2_days']

#verys similar like before, only test membership by isin
top_cust = ['a', 'c'] 
a = df[df['customer'].isin(top_cust)].groupby(['item','date'])['sales'].sum().rename('top_share')
df1 = df1.join(a, on=['item','date'])
df1['top_share'] = df1.groupby('item')['top_share'].apply(f).reset_index(drop=True, level=0) / df1['sales_last_2_days']
print (df1)
   item       date  sales  sales_last_2_days   a_share  top_share
0     1 2018-01-01     10                NaN       NaN        NaN
1     1 2018-01-02     12               10.0  0.200000   0.200000
2     1 2018-01-03      7               22.0  0.090909   0.318182
3     2 2018-01-04     10                NaN       NaN        NaN
4     2 2018-01-05     14               10.0  0.700000   1.000000
5     2 2018-01-06     12               24.0  0.416667   0.541667
6     2 2018-01-07     15               26.0  0.307692   0.500000
```

If want use `rolling` with days, it is more complicated:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['item','date'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
sales1 = (df1.set_index('date')
             .groupby('item')['sales']
             .rolling('2D', min_periods=1)
             .sum()
             .groupby('item')
             .shift()
             .rename('sales_last_2_days')
         )
df1 = df1.join(sales1, on=['item','date'])
```

---

```
df2 = df[df['customer'].eq('a')].groupby(['item','date'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
a = (df2.set_index('date')
        .groupby('item')[['sales']]
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D'))
        .reset_index(level=0)
        .groupby('item')['sales']
        .rolling('2D', min_periods=1)
        .sum()
        .groupby('item')
        .shift()
        .rename('a_share')
         )
print (a)
df1 = df1.join(a, on=['item','date'])
df1['a_share'] /= df1['sales_last_2_days']
```

---

```
top_cust = ['a', 'c'] 

df3 = df[df['customer'].isin(top_cust)].groupby(['item','date'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
b = (df3.set_index('date')
        .groupby('item')[['sales']]
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D'))
        .reset_index(level=0)
        .groupby('item')['sales']
        .rolling('2D', min_periods=1)
        .sum()
        .groupby('item')
        .shift()
        .rename('top_share')
         )
df1 = df1.join(b, on=['item','date'])
df1['top_share'] /= df1['sales_last_2_days']
```

---

```
print (df1)
   item       date  sales  sales_last_2_days   a_share  top_share
0     1 2018-01-01     10                NaN       NaN        NaN
1     1 2018-01-02     12               10.0  0.200000   0.200000
2     1 2018-01-03      7               22.0  0.090909   0.318182
3     2 2018-01-04     10                NaN       NaN        NaN
4     2 2018-01-05     14               10.0  0.700000   1.000000
5     2 2018-01-06     12               24.0  0.416667   0.541667
6     2 2018-01-07     15               26.0  0.307692   0.500000
```